# What is the mean of the \\?\ sequence?

Tags: c#, escaping

I had to make a code in c# that get a value from a .db file.
In this file i get path to a special folder(google drive) and there is the \\?\ sequence i'd like to know if this sequence have a special meaning.
this is the line i get :

local_sync_root_pathvalue\\?\C:\Users\User_Name\Google Drive

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Where did you find such sequence?

Comment: In the AppData/Local/Google/Drive/sync_config.db file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a special path prefix to allow you to have a path longer than 256 characters (but only if you are using a Unicode path).

See [the Windows API `CreateFile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function for details.

Also see [Naming Files, Paths and Namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thank you very mutch =) i was looking for the meaning of this for two days